# Помогите разобраться со скриптами javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Как вывести *email* фрагментами начиная с первого символа и увеличивая количество символов с каждой итерацией (с помощью *substring*), а также в обратном порядке? (Работаю в VS Code.)

Вот пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код:

```js
function getValueById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

function setValueById(id, value, append = true) {
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  element.value = append ?
    element.value + value + "\n" :
    value + "\n";
}

function btnSubmitOnClick() {
  let firstName = getValueById("txtFirstName");
  let lastName = getValueById("txtLastName");
  let User = 'User: ';
  let fullName = firstName + lastName;
  setValueById("txtResult", User + fullName);
  let Email = getValueById("txtEmail");
  let mail = 'Email: ';
  setValueById("txtResult", mail + Email);
  let yearOfBirth = getValueById("txtYearOfBirth");
  let years = 'Age: ';
  let age = new Date().getFullYear() - yearOfBirth;
  let tage;
  if (age > 0) {
    tage = 'Baby';
  }
  if (age > 2) {
    tage = 'Toddler';
  }
  if (age > 4) {
    tage = 'Kid';
  }
  if (age > 10) {
    tage = 'Tween';
  }
  if (age > 13) {
    tage = 'Teen';
  }
  if (age > 19) {
    tage = 'Young Adult';
  }
  if (age > 21) {
    tage = 'Adult';
  }
  let stage = 'Age stage: ';
  setValueById("txtResult", years + age);
  setValueById("txtResult", stage + tage);
  let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  if (yearOfBirth > currentYear) {
    alert('Year Of Birth can’t be more than current year');
  }
  if (lastName == false) {
    alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
  }
  if (Email == false) {
    alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
  }
  if (firstName == false) {
    alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
  }
  if (yearOfBirth == false) {
    alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  float: left;
}

.row {
  margin-top: 10px;
  clear: both;
  text-align: right;
}

.row label {
  float: left;
}

.row>input {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>First Name: </label><input id="txtFirstName" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Last Name: </label><input id="txtLastName" />
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>Email: </label><input id="txtEmail" />
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>Year Of Birth:</label><input id="txtYearOfBirth" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="btnSubmitOnClick();" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <textarea id="txtResult" cols="35" rows="45"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Все просто - цикл по нарастанию, цикл по убыванию.

Comment: Вот я попробовал записать, но не получается. вот код                                                                    
  let str = getValueById("txtEmail");
   for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    console.log(str.substring(0, 1));
   }
   setValueById("txtResult", str);

Comment: можете исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .container {
            float: left;
        }

        .row {
            margin-top: 10px;
            clear: both;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .row label {
            float: left;
        }

        .row>input {
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function getValueById(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id).value;
        }
        function setValueById(id, value, append = true) {
                let element = document.getElementById(id) ;
                element.value = append
                    ? element.value + value + "\n"
                    : value + "\n";     
            }
        function btnSubmitOnClick() {
            let firstName = getValueById("txtFirstName"); 
            let lastName = getValueById("txtLastName");
            let User = 'User: ';
            let fullName = firstName + lastName;
            setValueById("txtResult", User + fullName);
            let Email = getValueById("txtEmail");
            let mail = 'Email: ';   
            setValueById("txtResult", mail + Email);
            let yearOfBirth = getValueById("txtYearOfBirth");
            let years = 'Age: ';
            let age = new Date().getFullYear() - yearOfBirth;
            let tage;
            if (age > 0) {
                tage = 'Baby';
            }    
            if (age > 2) {
                tage = 'Toddler';
            }    
            if (age > 4) {
                tage = 'Kid';
            }    
            if (age > 10) {
                tage = 'Tween';
            }    
            if (age > 13) {
                tage = 'Teen';
            }    
            if (age > 19) {
                tage = 'Young Adult';
            }    
            if (age > 21) {
                tage = 'Adult';
            }    
            let stage = 'Age stage: ';
            setValueById("txtResult", years + age);
            setValueById("txtResult", stage + tage); 
            printEmail(Email);
            let currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
            if (yearOfBirth > currentYear) {
                alert('Year Of Birth can’t be more than current year');
            }
            if (lastName == false) {
                alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
            }
            if (Email == false) {
                alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
            }
            if (firstName == false) {
                alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
            }
            if (yearOfBirth == false) {
                alert('The <parameter label> is required.');
            }
        }
       
        function printEmail(email){
            let length = email.length;
            for (let i=1; i<=length; i++){
                setValueById("txtResult", email.substr(0, i));
            }
            for (let i=length; i>=0; i--){
                setValueById("txtResult", email.substr(0, i));
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <label>First Name: </label><input id="txtFirstName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <label>Last Name: </label><input id="txtLastName"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><label>Email: </label><input id="txtEmail"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row"><label>Year Of Birth:</label><input id="txtYearOfBirth"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" 
                        onclick="btnSubmitOnClick();"/> 
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <textarea id="txtResult" cols="35" rows="45"></textarea>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: большое спасибо вам за иной способ, но я вставил эту функцыю себе в скрипт и она не работает, не понимаю почему(

Comment: я изменил email на Email и все равно

Comment: беда... :) Вставил в ответ все полностью...

Comment: вы лучший))))))

Comment: а как нужно сделать чтобы имя и фамилия были через пробел, а не смыкались?

Answer (score 0):

Держи. Может еще что-то интересное для себя почерпнешь)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <style>
    .container {
      float: left;
    }

    .row {
      margin-top: 10px;
      clear: both;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .row label {
      float: left;
    }

    .row>input {
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <label>First Name: </label><input id="txtFirstName"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Last Name: </label><input id="txtLastName"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>Email: </label><input id="txtEmail"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row"><label>Year Of Birth:</label><input id="txtYearOfBirth"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input id="btnSubmit" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="btnSubmitOnClick();"/>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <textarea id="result" cols="35" rows="45" disabled></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  const resultField = document.getElementById('result')

  const clearResults = () => resultField.value = ''
  const getFieldValue = (fieldId) => document.getElementById(fieldId).value

  const getStage = (age) => {
    if (age < 0) throw new Error('Cant calculate age stage: Invalid age')
    if (age <= 2) return  'Baby'
    if (age <= 4) return  'Toddler'
    if (age <= 10) return  'Kid'
    if (age <= 13) return  'Tween'
    if (age <= 19) return  'Teen'
    if (age <= 21) return  'Young Adult'
    if (age > 21) return  'Adult'
  }

  const calculateAge = (birthYear) => new Date().getFullYear() - birthYear

  const generateLadder = (string) => {
    let result = ''
    for (let i = 1; i < string.length; i += 1) {
      result += `${string.substring(0, i)}\n`
    }
    for (let i = string.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      result += `${string.substring(0, i)}\n`
    }
    return result
  }

  const generateResult = (firstName, lastName, email, age) => {
    const userStroke = `User: ${firstName} ${lastName}`
    const emailStroke = `Email: ${email}`
    const ageStroke = `Age: ${age}`
    const ageStageStroke = `Age stage: ${getStage(age)}`
    return `${userStroke}\n${emailStroke}\n${ageStroke}\n${ageStageStroke}\n${generateLadder(email)}`
  }

  const isValuesNotEmpty = (...values) => values
    .reduce((acc, value) => {
      if (acc) {
        return value.trim() !== ''
      }
      return false
    }, true)

  function btnSubmitOnClick() {
    clearResults()

    const firstName = getFieldValue('txtFirstName')
    const lastName = getFieldValue('txtLastName')
    const email = getFieldValue('txtEmail')
    const birthYear = getFieldValue('txtYearOfBirth')
    const age = calculateAge(birthYear)

    const isDataValid = isValuesNotEmpty(firstName, lastName, email, birthYear)
    if (!isDataValid) return alert('All fields are required')
    if (age <= 0) return alert('Set correct birth year')

    resultField.value = generateResult(firstName, lastName, email, age)
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```